# How do I define an explicit SVN revision for a Composer repository?

Tags: php, svn, composer-php

I'm trying to include *google-api-php-client* library to my project using Composer. Simpliest way is to get library from VCS trunk branch, but I think it's not the best idea in my case. Much better will be point to some stable library state (tag or revision). Whereas there's no tags available, get a particular svn revision is the only option. But I have no idea how to do this.

I tried different package configs with no success, something like this:

```
{
  "repositories":[
    {
        "type":"package",
        "package":{
            "name":"project/google-api-php-client",
            "version":"0.2.1",
            "source":{
                "type":"svn",
                "url":"http://google-api-php-client.googlecode.com/svn",
                "reference":"trunk/?r=515"
            }
        }
    }
  ]
}
```

Whether it possible at all to checkout svn revision with composer? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Good question, I've been wondering how to do this for a while and finally broke down and read the code to figure out how it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Using a package repository when you are defining the version you can specify a revision in the reference.  An example from my wordpress composer.json

```
{
    "repositories": [
        "type": "package",
        "package": {
            "name": "wordpress-plugin/wp-minify",
            "type": "wordpress-plugin",
            "version": "1.2",
            "source": {
                "type": "svn",
                "url": "http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/wp-minify",
                "reference": "trunk@691320"
            },
            "require": {
                "composer/installers": "~1.0"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

This installs the plugin from the trunk with an explicit revision of `691320`.

Answer (score 0):

The version can be set in the require part (that you don't show).

The only SVN options available are:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "http://svn.example.org/projectA/",
            "trunk-path": "Trunk",
            "branches-path": "Branches",
            "tags-path": "Tags"
        }
    ]
}
```

Look's like you want to use a package, but you could also just define this repository and `require` the appropriate version (can you tag? It's easier).

You could also try to put the revision insive the `version` parameter but I don't think that will work.

Also, the documentation state that about the "trunk" path:

> Since Subversion has no native concept of branches and tags, Composer
>   assumes by default that code is located in $url/trunk, $url/branches
>   and $url/tags. If your repository has a different layout you can
>   change those values.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As you said, putting revision number  inside the `version` parameter won't work. For now, I decide to leave this library standalone in my project, not under Composer.